# Compare strings in C# like in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Good day for all ;)
Can anyone help me to find algorithms or already resolved solutions for comparing strings like SQL do it.

For instance
In SQL I can compare strings for

> = or <=, >, <
>   e.t.c.

In C# as known we can't do it.

I want to compare something like

"aa" > "b" "ab" < "aa" "abc" >= "bca" and so on..

Also, maybe someone knows by what logic SQL does it?

Comment: Can u please describe more?

Answer (score 7):

Strings implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can use [CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
void Main()
{
    if ("a".CompareTo("b") < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A is less than B");
    }

    if ("a".CompareTo("b") <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A is less than or equal to B");
    }

    if ("a".CompareTo("a") == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A equals A");
    }

    if ("c".CompareTo("b") > 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C is greater than B");
    }

    if ("c".CompareTo("b") >= 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C is greater than or equal to B");
    }
}
```

However, if you want case-insensitive comparison then you will need to use the overload of [string.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to ignore case. The logic is the same though.

Comment: There's a *flaw* in such comparison: what if left argument is `null`? `null.CompareTo(...)` throws an exception.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Well, yes - error checking and defensive programming is left to the implementor. That's hardly a flaw in the code I've posted!

Answer (score 3):

Well, `"aa" < "ab"` equals to

```
  bool result = String.Compare("aa", "ab") < 0;
```

and so on:

```
 // "abc" >= "bca" 
 bool result = String.Compare("abc", "bca") >= 0;
```

the general pattern for `"left" <=> "right"` is

```
 String.Compare("left", "right") <=> 0
```

since `String.Compare(left, right)` returns

- *negative* value (say, -123) when `left < right`
- *zero* when `left == right`
- *postivie* value (e.g. 789) when 'left > right'

Comment: @Kernighan: `Compare(left, right)` returns *positive* value (`> 0`) if `left` *greater* than `right`, it returns *zero* if `left` *equals* to `right`, and *negative* value when `left` less than `right`.

Comment: Thank you, i understood.